# Extract string text into another strings

Tags: java, android, database, string, split

I got a string like this:

`String text = number|name|url||number2|name2|url2`

Now I have written a loop

```
int initialiaze = 0;
for(i = initialize; i > text.length(); i++) {
    //do the work
}
```

In this loop I want to extract `number` to one string, `name` to one string, `url` to one string and if I reach `||` do a action (e.g insert this three string into db) if this action is done, start again an extract `number2`, `name2` and `url2` into string and do a action.

Is this possible? Can you tell me how? I dont get it.

Comment: take a look at the StringTokenizer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356251/string-tokenizer-in-java and http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=236

Comment: Are the `|` dividers literally there, or are you showing that just to illustrate the division?

Comment: I added the dividers, because I thought they would be helpful to split the string. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `.split()` method for strings.

```
String[] bigParts = myString.split("\\|\\|");
for(String part : bigParts)
{
    String[] words = part.split("\\|");
    //save to db or what you want
}
```

Comment: Would there be a reason to go with one (.split() vs. tokenizer) over the other?

Comment: I've never used tokenizer so I cant answer your question. But answer of Sergey Benner looks complicated.

Comment: Does this method go so long through the string till it ends?

Comment: `words` is a StringArray, am I right? How can I log (e.g via `Log.D`) or print the Array with a textView (e.g via `setText`)? Only to test if its work :)

Comment: for(String w : words) { textView.setText(w); Thread.sleep(2000); }
after this you'll see in your textView each word for 2 seconds.

Comment: Its only your split code, the string and the setText code. Everything on my onCreate method. very simple.

Comment: Of course you'll get the last one if you're writing this in onCreate method because component is not visible until onCreate is not completed. You have to make say a button and do this in that buttons onClick event.

Comment: @Leandros I'm not your debugger :D try to debug your application. You asked a question how to split, I answered. Then think yourself. Nothing personal ;-)

Answer (score 3):

for your case

```
    StringTokenizer stPipe = null;
    StringTokenizer stDblPipe = null;
    String firstPipeElement=null;
    stPipe = new StringTokenizer(text, "|");        
    if (stPipe.hasMoreElements())
    {
      firstPipeElement= stPipe.nextElement().toString();
    .......
    if(firstPipeElement.equals("||"))
      {
      stDblPipe = new StringTokenizer(firstPipeElement , "||");
   .....

      }
    }
```

---

hope this helps

Comment: What is firstPipeElement? Another string you only forgot?

Answer (score 1):

Java is not my language, but worth try,

```
String text = number|name|url||number2|name2|url2
String[] temp;
String[] temp2;
int i ;
temp = text.split("\\|\\|")
for(i=0;i<temp.length();i++){
 temp2 = temp[i].split("\\|");
 String no = temp2[0];
 String name = temp2[1];
 String url = temp2[2];

 // Do processing with no, name, url

}
```

I hope, this would help

Comment: edit your answer and escape '|' characters. And already change single quotes to double ('||' --> "\\|\\|")

Comment: Thanks @Ademiban for pointing it out and Ranrag for editing.

Just out of curiousity ( I dont know java ), wont it run without escaping ? Also if it would be a single character does java will it have single quotes or double quotes ?

Because, in C#, text.Split('|') is okay and it does not have any splitting for strings.

Comment: Now your answer is right :) No, in Java there are only two split methods and both takes as argument a text, not a single symbol, so you have to put your text into double quotes even if there is only one symbol. See this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html