# How to extract keys and values from string array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am doing an android app, where i read the text from an image and i get an output string like below,

> NAME : michael /nPHONE NO: 771234521/n e-Mail: michael@gmai|.com /nCompany:
>   Google/n

I want to extract them individually as a string, and assign to a variable like,

String Name = "michael";
String Phone = "771234521";

how can i achieve like this,here is my piece of code,

```
input.setText(recognizedText);
String[] separated = recognizedText.split("/");
for (String s: separated)
{

}
```

Comment: So, you can split them by `/` but you cannot split them again?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think want to parse your fields into a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and that they are separated on the newline character (`\n`). Perhaps like this -

```
// Convert the string in to a Map<String, String>.
public static Map<String, String> toMap(String in) {
  // the return map.
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  // a tokenizer on newline
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in, "\n");
  while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {      // while there are lines.
    String token = st.nextToken();  // get the line.
    String[] kv = token.split(":"); // split on colon.
    if (kv.length > 1) {            // check that there's a key and a
                                    // value.
      map.put(kv[0].trim(), kv[1].trim()); // add it to
                                           // the map.
    }
  }
  return map; // return the map.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "NAME : michael \nPHONE NO: 771234521\n"
      + " e-Mail: michael@gmai|.com \nCompany: Google\n";
  Map<String, String> map = toMap(str);
  System.out.println(map);
}
```

Which outputs this here -

```
{NAME=michael, e-Mail=michael@gmai|.com, Company=Google, PHONE NO=771234521}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "NAME : michael /nPHONE NO: 771234521/n e-Mail: michael@gmai|.com /nCompany: Google/n";

        String[] str = s.split("/n");
            for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
             {
             str[i]=str[i].trim();
             }
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            System.out.println(str[k]);
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
NAME : michael 
PHONE NO: 771234521
e-Mail: michael@gmai|.com 
Company: Google
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String Tokenizer` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356251/string-tokenizer-in-java)

Tokenize the string based on your `delimeter` `/`

Answer (score 0):

```
String src = "NAME : michael /nPHONE NO: 771234521/n e-Mail: michael@gmai|.com /nCompany: Google/n";
        String noLineSrc = src.replace("/n", ",");
        String[] couples = noLineSrc.split(",");
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(String couple : couples) {
            String[] coupleValue = couple.split(":");
            result.put(coupleValue[0].trim(), coupleValue[1].trim());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys are: `"NAME:", "PHONE NO:", "e-Mail:", and "Company:"`.

After splitting the string with `split("/n")`, you can do a `str[i].contains("Name:")` to check for the key.

The value comes after the `":"`.  So, `int pos = str[i].indexof(":") + 1` will be the starting position of the value.

`String value = str[i].substring(pos)` gives you the value.

Then `value.trim()` to remove spaces.